# Symfony error for login

Tags: symfony, authentication

In Symfony I am trying to create a loginpage, but I get the following error:

> Variable "error" does not exist in
>   QuizBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig at line 37

Can someone help me with this?
Here is my code:

**Class:**

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('', array('name' => $name));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome")
     */
    public function welcomeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();



        return $this->render('@Quiz/Default/welcome.html.twig', array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**Twig File:**

```
<div id="loginfields" style="display: none">
                {% if error %}
                    <div>{{error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')}}</div>
                {% endif %}

                <form class="form-signin" action="{{path('welcome')}}" method="post">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"  name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>

                    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="_password" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/admin" />

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**Security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
            QuizBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

    providers:
            our_db_provider:
                entity:
                    class: QuizBundle:User

    firewalls:
           main:
               anonymous: ~
               form_login:
                  login_path: welcome
                  check_path: welcome
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `error` variable (or to avoid an exception/error when you try to use a variable that maybe not exist) you need to check if it exist like this:

```
{% if error is defined %}
    <div>{{error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

More infos on [define Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem is that I have a login.html.twig file which is identical to the one posted in my question but in this one I have `<form class="form-signin" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">`. Then in the Securitycontroller class where the route is I have: `@Route("/login", name="login")`, and in my security.yml I have: `login_path: login check_path: login` And everything is working

Comment: Never mind, it was a stupid mistake from my part as I had /welcome path somewhere else in a different controller.